# How to get the row_numbers in sql where condition is a specific date difference?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions

I am stuck with a portion of my query to extract the row_numbers that have a date difference of at least three months. So in the example below I would like to extract row_number 1 (always the first one), 5 and 6. So after row_number 1 the row_numbers with a date_diff > 3 months (and after second extracted row_number applying this condition again until None. Is  there any function or way within SQL that allows for such a condition to be made?

```
table_name: users  

id  row_number  User    date          
---|----------|-------|---------------------|
1  |1         | Usr1  | 2017-10-01 12:35:00 | 
2  |2         | Usr1  | 2017-10-01 12:35:00 | 
3  |3         | Usr1  | 2017-12-03 07:47:00 |
4  |4         | Usr1  | 2018-01-10 07:47:00 | 
5  |5         | Usr1  | 2018-02-10 07:47:00 | 
6  |6         | Usr1  | 2018-04-10 07:47:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` function to calculate the difference:

```
select *
from (
  select id, row_number, "User", date, 
         date - lag(date) over (order by id) as diff
  from users
) t
where diff is null  -- first row
   or diff > interval '3 month';
```

Comment: The right function for this task. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to compare intervals as months.  I think they are normally represented as a number of days.

So, I would phrase this as:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, lag(date) over (order by id) as prev_date
      from users u
     )  u
where prev_date is null or prev_date < date - interval '3 month';
```

If the `or` bothers you, you can remove it by using default values in the `lag()`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, lag(date, 1, date - interval '100 year') over (order by id) as prev_date
      from users u
     )  u
where prev_date < date - interval '3 month';
```

Comment: Nice variation on the aforementioned solution. I must have mentioned that I was working with Redshift so I had to use days instead of month. Thank you.

Comment: @Gamelogic . . . In RedShift, you can use `add_months()` instead.